# Why am i getting a empty array, when I am calling from parse cloud code

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Here's my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("findRestaurantName", function(request, response) {
  getRestaurantInfo(request.params.username,{
    success: function(things) {
      response.success(things);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("username lookup failed");
    }
  });
});

function getRestaurantInfo(restaurantName, callback){
  var query = new Parse.Query("RestaurantDataBase");
  query.equalTo("name", restaurantName);
  query.find({
    success: function(results){
      callback.success(results);
    },
    error: function(){
      callback.error("lookup fail");
    }
  });
}
```

how come when I try to run the code on Xcode, I get an empty array from the Parse function?

Comment: On SO, this kind of question is apt to get closed (there's a category of close-able question called "Why is this code not working").  It means the community would like to understand what you've tried so far to solve the problem.  e.g. have you tried commenting out `query.equalTo("name", restaurantName);` on the theory that maybe there's no RestaurantDataBase instance with the name you're passing?

Comment: you have to display your effort, if you don't know why your code is not working, you should take programming classes, take time and debug it, hire specialist, hire a mentor. etc. etc. etc. in other words put efforts.